# JavaScriptExecutor + WebDrive com erro: Cannot read property 'click' of null

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

**Edited to english**

I am browsing a page that ** I do not have edit access ** and need to click on a text that references a JavaScript function.

- Navigation using Selenium WebDriver;
- Using ChromeDriver;
- Using JavaScriptExecutor to click on html tag

```html
<div id="btn-certificacao-digital" style="display: block;">
     <p>AUTENTICAÇÃO COM</p>
     <br>
     <strong>CERTIFICADO DIGITAL</strong>
     <a href="javascript:ICPShow();" id="btnCallLogin" class="access-details"> 
     </a>
</div>
```

I'm trying this:

```java
public class ArispCrawler {
    public void mainArispFlow() {

        WebDriver driver = MainWebDriver.AutenticaMock();
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Arisp")).click();
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("document.getElementById('btnCallLogin').click()");
    }
}
```

Configuration of my WebDrive:

```java
    public static WebDriver ConfigNavDrive() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://Program Files//Selenium//chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        return (driver);
    }
```

Error log:

```
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
[1571537382.956][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
2019-10-19 23:09:44.983  INFO 15576 --- [ null to remote] o.o.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake    : Detected dialect: W3C
[1571537387.001][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: Cannot read property 'click' of null
  (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.120)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'NOTETI-20', ip: '192.168.0.106', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_211'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 77.0.3865.120, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 77.0.3865.40 (f484704e052e0..., userDataDir: C:\Users\tleite\AppData\Loc...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:55279}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: 5a7294d553560d624269a181a6406b00
```

**OBS: Other simple navigations are working correctly, just using JavaScriptExecutor is giving the problem. Also performed test by clicking div but it didn't work**

**Updated**

May the problem is when i using js.executeScript("document.getElementById('btnCallLogin').click()"), the selenium is open another guide in the current window, so it lost the context, but i dont know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

After to long work, I find the problem:

A previous step in de navigation, i clicked in a href that open new tab in navigator:

```
<a href="arisp/login.html" target="_blank">Arisp</a>
```

I use this to open in the same tab:

```
public class ArispCrawler {
    public void mainArispFlow() throws InterruptedException {

        WebDriver driver = MainWebDriver.AutenticaMock();
        String urlArisp = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Arisp"))
                .getAttribute("href");
        driver.get(urlArisp);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("document.getElementById('btnCallLogin').click()");
        //String urlAutenticacao = driver.findElement(By.id("btnCallLogin"))
        //      .getAttribute("javascript:ICPShow();"); 
    }
}
```